# No article or the definite article with uncountable nouns and "of"

Tags: articles

Tell me please which of the following sentences is correct.

> 1. He showed his resentment in direct expression of anger.
> 2. He showed his resentment in the direct expression of anger.

Although I have seen peope use it without "the", I suppose the second one is correct, because "anger" modifies "expression."

Could anyone tell me if I am wrong, and if I am, then explain it for me please.

Comment: I'd say, "**He showed his resentment in a direct expression of anger**".

Comment: Could you explain why please?

Comment: The example is unclear. Is the "direct expression of anger" coming from "He" or from a third party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you that *the* should be used. Leaving out *direct* makes this even clearer to me which of the two is correct. I also think that *a/an* could be used, with a different meaning  :

> He showed his resentment in the expression of anger.
>   He showed his resentment in an expression of anger.
>   He showed his resentment in expression of anger.

The first option talks about his response on several occasions. It was habitual. The second option talks about a particular incident. As a native English speaker, the third option sounds wrong to me.

I agree with Ringo that instead of *in* you could use *by* or *through*. Again *the* or *an* are correct uses but not no article at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence 1 is correct:

> He showed his resentment in direct expression of anger.

The article "the" would be used to refer to a specific, previously-mentioned ***direct expression of anger*** -- an expression of anger that the reader would have already known about and is being discussed further in this sentence. Because these sample sentences are meant to stand alone without previous context, the "the" ought to be omitted.

Furthermore, there is some ambiguity in the meaning of the sentence. It could mean one of two things:

A. *He expressed resentment toward other people's direct expressions of anger. He didn't like it when people showed anger directly and resented that kind of behavior.* You could clearly communicate this by saying:

> He showed his resentment toward direct expression of anger.

Or:

B. *He showed his direct expression of anger by resenting the thing that made him angry.* You could communicate this by saying:

> He showed his resentment through direct expression of anger.

I think it's unclear whether resentment is a direct expression of anger, but I'll leave that open to interpretation.

You can read more about *the definite article* here:

http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/

You can also use "a" as @sovereignsun mentioned, but it's not preferable to no article.

Comment: Beyond the article issue, could you explain what the statement is actually saying? I don't think it is written correctly.

Comment: I also wonder what the word 'expression' would be used as countable or uncountable? I look it up in a dictionary, saying  it could be both.

Comment: @user3169 I think I see the potential confusion you see, but I would think the narrator would instead say **resentment *toward*** or **resentment *of*** instead of **resentment *in***. But I'm not sure?

Comment: I suggested a fix.

Comment: @dan I believe "expression" as used in ***direct expression of anger*** is countable (***direct expressions of anger***) or can also be uncountable (***direct expression of anger*** containing many separate expressions)

Comment: Much better. It could also be plural "through direct expressions" when expressing a mannerism rather than a specific occurrence.